# conflicting types for s32_t in c code for STM32F7xx

Tags: c, arm, stm32

I implement LwIP on STM32F7. And I have a problem. When I include

```
#include "lwip.h"
```

I get this warning: **conflicting types for 's32_t'**
It is in the cc.h file:

```
typedef signed     long    s32_t;
```

Here is picture with problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfTYS.jpg

What is wrong, and how I can solve this?

Comment: The best solution is to #include <cstdint> or <stdint.h> and use the int32_t type from there.

Comment: `s32_t` is probably already defined in one of the header files you include. Try to remove `typedef signed     long    s32_t;` and see if it compiles.

Comment: And the definition in the headers is probably that it is an `int`, which, though the same size, is not compatible.

Comment: BTW: what is `cc.h`?  Where does it come from? Is it a file of yours?

Comment: No it is not. It is come from: LwIP/system/arch/cc.h

Comment: @Jirka please show the corresponding line in `LwIP/system/arch/cc.h`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`s32_t` is probably already defined in one of the header files you include. Try to remove `typedef signed long s32_t;` and the other similar lines from `cc.h`.

This error can be reproduced simply with following two lines.

```
typedef signed int  s32_t;
typedef signed long s32_t;
```

[**Live demonstration here**](https://www.ideone.com/DKImOW)

Also search for typedefs of `s32_t` in `lwip.h` and in `cc.h`, this should give you further clues.

Comment: I commend this line and now program is without error:
'//typedef unsigned   char    u8_t;
//typedef signed     char    s8_t;
//typedef unsigned   short   u16_t;
//typedef signed     short   s16_t;
//typedef unsigned   long    u32_t;
//typedef signed     long    s32_t;'